# Remover e inserir caracteres na mesma posição

Tags: php

Eu teho o seguinte problema em PHP

Preciso remover os caracteres de uma string, e depois inserir na mesma posição. Atualmente estou fazendo dessa forma, mas estou aberto a sugestões.

Tenho uma string inicial: `te12te`

Eu removo os números dessa string e armazeno o caractere e a posição em dois arrays:

```
$stringInicial = "te12te";

//Processo de remoção resulta em:
$arrayCaracteres = ["1", "2"];
$arrayPosicao = [2, 3];
$stringInicial = "tete";

//As letras da string passam por um processo e são alteradas seguindo uma lógica
$stringInicial = "vivi";

//Preciso agora inserir os caracteres na mesma posição
```

Dado essas informações, eu preciso inserir os caracteres removidos no ínicio, na mesma posição. Ou seja, o resultado deve ser `vi12vi`

EDIT: O procedimento realizado é a cifra de PlayFair, segue o código que faz esse procedimento:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($plainText); $i += 2) {
    //compute coords
    $x0 = array_search($plainText[$i], $this->matrix) % 5;
    $y0 = intval(array_search($plainText[$i], $this->matrix) / 5);
    $x1 = array_search($plainText[$i + 1], $this->matrix) % 5;
    $y1 = intval(array_search($plainText[$i + 1], $this->matrix) / 5);

    if ($y0 == $y1) {
        //same line
        $encrypted .= $this->matrix[5 * $y0 + (($x0 + 1) % 5)];
        $encrypted .= $this->matrix[5 * $y1 + (($x1 + 1) % 5)];
    } elseif ($x0 == $x1) {
        //same column
        $encrypted .= $this->matrix[5 * (($y0 + 1) % 5) + $x0];
        $encrypted .= $this->matrix[5 * (($y1 + 1) % 5) + $x1];
    } else {
        //line and column are different
        $encrypted .= $this->matrix[(5 * $y0 + $x1)];
        $encrypted .= $this->matrix[(5 * $y1 + $x0)];
    }
 }
```

Comment: str_replace("te","vi",$stringInicial;  https://ideone.com/cNRiC1

Comment: Essa string não é sempre a mesma, usei essa só para criar o exemplo.

Comment: e qual é o padrão

Comment: é uma cifra de encriptação, e eu preciso ignorar os números na hora de encriptar. Não existe um padrão para a string inicial

Comment: Serão sempre os números que serão removidos e inseridos?

Comment: então, já é um padrão

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss serão sempre os números e caracteres especiais ()!$#@ e etc

Comment: Tem como descrever melhor como funciona essa alteração das letras? Estava pensando aqui e não consegui pensar em um jeito bonito de fazer. Todas pareceram gambiarras. Quem sabe é possível integrar as duas partes e fazer algo melhor.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o processo é a cifra de PlayFair, editei para tentar mostrar como é

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que a posição seja cada byte e que elas podem não estar juntas você pode utilizar dois `mb_substr`.

```
foreach($arrayPosicao as $index => $posicao){

    $stringAtePosicao = mb_substr($stringInicial, 0, $posicao, '8bit');
    $stringDepoisPosicao = mb_substr($stringInicial, $posicao, null, '8bit');

    $stringInicial = $stringAtePosicao . $arrayCaracteres[$index] . $stringDepoisPosicao;

}
```

Você pode compactar isso em uma só linha, mas acho que assim fica mais claro. Primeiro pegamos toda a string até a posição, depois adicionamos o conteúdo e pegamos o resto da string até o final.

---

Resultado:

```
vi12vi
```

---

Isso também funciona cm várias substituições, se necessário, por exemplo:

```
$stringInicial = "te12te3abc4";

$arrayCaracteres = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
$arrayPosicao = [2, 3, 6, 10];
$stringInicial = "tete";

$stringInicial = "viviabc";


foreach($arrayPosicao as $index => $posicao){

    $stringChange  = mb_substr($stringInicial, 0, $posicao, '8bit');
    $stringChange .= $arrayCaracteres[$index];
    $stringChange .= mb_substr($stringInicial, $posicao, null, '8bit');

    $stringInicial = $stringChange;

}

echo $stringInicial;
```

Resultado:

```
vi12vi3abc4
```

Comment: Por que usar por byte? Qual a eficiência disso se a?

Comment: @FernandoBagno, porque não se sabe da onde vem a posição. Considere `aç1`, qual a posição de `1`? Se for por byte será 3, se for UTF8. Se a posição for por caractere usando utf8, a posição será 2. O autor da pergunta não menciona como o `$arrayPosicao` é feita, por isso deduzi que seja por byte e usei o `mb_*` que permite definir outro tipo (se a posição for por caractere UTF8, basta definir `utf8`). A razão de definir `8bit` é porque PHP é "bugadasso", seu comportamento é alterado pelo `mbstring.func_overload` e `mb_internal_encoding`, então definir `8bit` é por segurança.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela explicação. Na minha resposta considerei ele usando str_pos da vida.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que você manterá a string com o mesmo tamanho, você pode usar **substr_replace** para isso:

```
foreach($arrayCaracteres as $k=>$value) {
    substr_replace($stringInicial, $value, 0, $arrayPosicao[$k]);
}
```

- Pra cada posição encontrada, faz a alteração durante o foreach com o **$value** e o índice do array de posições ($k);
- O **0** índica se a contagem de caracteres é a partir da primeira posição;